# Pytest and SqlAlchemy Rollback between tests

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I have a domain model and have used classical/imperative mapping to map across to SqlAlchemy. I'm trying to set up some tests for SqlAlchemy, but I can't get it to rollback after each test (so that each test starts with the database in it's 'original' state. If I add rows in one test, they are currently carrying over to the next test, which I don't want.

I've worked through two tutorials [1](https://itnext.io/setting-up-transactional-tests-with-pytest-and-sqlalchemy-b2d726347629), [2](https://aalvarez.me/posts/setting-up-a-sqlalchemy-and-pytest-based-test-suite/) which aren't working, there is also some info on the [SqlAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/12/orm/session_transaction.html) (which looks like what is used for tutorial 1) but also not working. There are a couple of Stacks, but are either unanswered or not really what I want to do.

I can't decipher the Rollback, it just doesn't seem to work.

model.py

```
@dataclass(frozen=False)
class Dummy:
    _id: int
    value: int
```

orm.py

```
mapper_registry = registry()

dummy = Table(
    "dummy",
    mapper_registry.metadata,
    Column("_id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    Column("value", Integer, nullable=False)
)

def start_mappers():
    mapper_registry.map_imperatively(Dummy, dummy)
```

test_orm.py

```
#test 1
def test_inmem_dummy_mapped(session):
    dummy = Dummy(1, 1)
    with session:
       session.add(dummy)
       session.add(Dummy(2,4))
       session.commit()

    results = session.query(Dummy).all()
    assert results == [Dummy(1, 1), Dummy(2,4)]

#test 2
def test_inmem_nested_transaction_A(session):
    dummy = Dummy(3, 1)
    with session:
       session.add(dummy)
       session.add(Dummy(4,6))
       session.commit()

    results = session.query(Dummy).all()
    assert results == [Dummy(3, 1), Dummy(4,6)]
```

conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def engine():
    engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True, future=True)
    return engine

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def connection(request, engine):
    connection = engine.connect()
    def teardown():
        connection.close()
    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return connection

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def init_db_orm_mappings(connection, request):
    mapper_registry.metadata.bind = connection
    mapper_registry.metadata.create_all()
    start_mappers()
    def teardown():
        mapper_registry.metadata.drop_all()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)

#session version 1 [\[from link\]][1]
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse = True)
def session(connection, request, engine):
    connection.commit() #!!
    transaction = connection.begin()
    session = Session(bind=connection)
    session.begin_nested()
    yield session
    transaction.rollback()

#session version 2 [\[from link\]][2]
@pytest.fixture(scope="function", autouse = True)
def session(connection, request, engine):
    transaction = connection.begin()
    session = Session(bind=connection)
    session.begin_nested()

    @event.listens_for(session, "after_transaction_end")
    def restart_savepoint(db_session, transaction):
        if transaction.nested and not transaction._parent.nested:
            session.expire_all()
            session.begin_nested()

    def teardown():
        session.close()
        transaction.rollback()
        session.rollback()

    request.addfinalizer(teardown)
    return session
```

Using the version 1 fixture, test 2 fails because the data from test 1 is still in the DB and has not been rolled back according to the teardown after the yield. Using the version 2 fixture, the same thing happens.

I'm on my second day of this issue. I'm working through both the PyTest and SqlAlchemy docs, but obviously, there are week's of reading in each and I can't seem to find any reason as to why these rollbacks wouldn't work.

There is [some additional stuff](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/sqlite.html#serializable-isolation-savepoints-transactional-ddl) on the SqlAlchemy docs about problems with Sqlite using the SAVEPOINT. The docs have some code but I can't figure out how to implement it into what I have already written:

```
@event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
def do_connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    # disable pysqlite's emitting of the BEGIN statement entirely.
    # also stops it from emitting COMMIT before any DDL.
    dbapi_connection.isolation_level = None

@event.listens_for(engine, "begin")
def do_begin(conn):
    # emit our own BEGIN
    conn.exec_driver_sql("BEGIN")
```

UPDATE:
So, I think i can confirm it is an issue with Sqlite not playing nicely with SqlAlchemy and SAVEPOINT. I couldn't figure out where to put the two methods above to see if that would make it work. It would be ideal if that were possible.

In the meantime, I created a SQL database in Sql Server Management Studio (didn't create any tables) and then changed the engine fixture to the below then used the #version2 code for the session.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def engine():
    connection_url = URL.create(
        "mssql+pyodbc",
        username="someDBusername",
        password="someDBpassword",
        host="127.0.0.1",
        port=1234,
        database="DBForTest",
        query={
            "driver": "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
            "Encrypt": "yes",
            "TrustServerCertificate": "yes",
        },
    )
    engine = create_engine(connection_url)
```

This seems to work to rollback any inserts between tests, though it doesn't reset primary keys between tests, so even though the data is gone, the primary key index is still +1...